curl -I google.com is forbidden but ping will work | for every url
i stuck for a week on this, error when hit apt update or install almost every package
curl -I http://google.com got error :
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx/1.14.1
Date: Mon, 19 Aug 2024 10:28:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 332
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html

ping work normally but curl said this category is blocked by sdns
root@hse:/var/www/html# sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 208.91.112.55 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 208.91.112.55 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 208.91.112.55 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 208.91.112.55 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 208.91.112.55 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 208.91.112.55 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 208.91.112.55 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 208.91.112.55 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


Guess it's duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/57146103/17526957, if not check your DNS setting in /etc/resolv.conf , check if your apt works or not

@assaabriiii fire wall is off try so many dns but not answered

@hossein USUALLY I would suggest that if your firewall is off to check what DNS servers your system is set to use and see if those systems resolve direct queries or not.  However, if you are on a corporate network or such, you likely have filtration in place in your environment blocking connectivity external, especially if there's a proxy in your network.  403 Forbidden from an nginx 1.14 box sounds like someone's trying to set up a forward proxy in your onetwork with NGINX, and they've done it wrong.

It might be a network traffic is being blocked or filtered, most likely caused by DNS filtering service (secure DNS)
first check your system proxy via:
echo $http_proxy
echo $https_proxy

then update your apt source list
check your noble-security, it should be bionic-security or focal-security etc, depending on your Ubuntu version
if none worked change your DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf
add the following line:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

for your CA Certificates, ensures your SSL certificates are up to date
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates

worth checking if your port 80 is closed by another application
